# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined Countdown-react-circle-timer

Tags: react-redux, countdowntimer

I am trying to display a circle timer under my image, that will exit the page after 10 seconds. But it keeps giving 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined'. Can anyone help?

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { CountdownCircleTimer } from "react-countdown-circle-timer";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useHistory } from "react-router";
import "./ChatView.css";
import { selectSelectedImage } from "./features/appSlice";

function ChatView() {
  const selectedImage = useSelector(selectSelectedImage);
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!selectedImage) {
      exit();
    }
  }, [selectedImage]);

  const exit = () => {
    history.replace("/chats");
  };

  return (
    <div className="chatView">
      <img src={selectedImage} onClick={exit} alt="" />
      <CountdownCircleTimer
        isPlaying
        duration={10}
        strokeWidth={6}
        size={50}
        color={[
          ["#004777", 0.33],
          ["#F7B801", 0.33],
          ["#A30000", 0.33],
        ]}
      >
        {({ remainingTime }) => {
          if (remainingTime === 0) {
            exit();
          }
        }}
      </CountdownCircleTimer>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ChatView;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure because I could not get your actual problem through your description but I think the error is because of color property that is

```
color={[
          ["#004777", 0.33],
          ["#F7B801", 0.33],
          ["#A30000", 0.33],
        ]}
```

This could not be mapped so it needs to be like this

```
color=[
          ["#004777", 0.33],
          ["#F7B801", 0.33],
          ["#A30000", 0.33],
        ]
```

Still that's not a sure answer you can try this one too if you haven't yet